# Parsing serial communication in case statements between Arduino and Python after 1st char

Tags: python, arduino

I'm having trouble in my case statement. A python script either serial.writes an "s" for sensor information or "r" for relay information. The sensor information part works perfectly. I'm having trouble getting the relay information right. The python script sends out an "r" followed by relay information which should be stored in array[x]. The arduino acknowledges the "r" in the case statement but doesnt process the proceeding packet which follows. All I get are empty arrays. I had a look here [Nick Gammons Serial page](http://gammon.com.au/serial) but can't figure out how to get it to work in my situation, I just don't have the experience.

Any help is much appreciated.

ARDUINO CODE

```
void SerialCommunication()
{ 
  if (Serial.available()>0)
  {
    char inChar = Serial.read(); 
    switch (inChar) 
    {
      case 'r':
        Sensors();
        break;
      case 'w':
        Relays();
        ProcessRelays();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  } 
}

void Relays()
{
  while (Serial.available() ==0);
  // Read all serial data available, as fast as possible
  while(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char inChar = Serial.read();
    if(inChar == SOP)
    {
       index = 0;
       inData[index] = '\0';
       started = true;
       ended = false;
    }
    else if(inChar == EOP)
    {
       ended = true;
       break;
    }
    else
    {
      if(index < 79)
      {
        inData[index] = inChar;
        index++;
        inData[index] = '\0';
      }
    }
  }

  // We are here either because all pending serial
  // data has been read OR because an end of
  // packet marker arrived. Which is it?

  if(started && ended)
  {
    // The end of packet marker arrived. Process the packet

    if (strlen(inData) > 0)
   {

      char *token = strtok(inData, ",");
      if(token)
      {
         index = 0;

         array[index] = atoi(token);

         while (token = strtok(NULL, ","))
         {
            array[index++] = atoi(token);
         }
      }
    }

    // Reset for the next packet
    started = false;
    ended = false;
    index = 0;
    inData[index] = '\0';
  }
}
void ProcessRelays()
{
  Serial.println(array[0]);
  Serial.println(array[1]);
  Serial.println(array[2]);
}
```

PYTHON CODE

```
#Import libraries
import serial
import string
import MySQLdb
import pprint
from time import strftime

#Connect to arduino
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=9600, timeout = 2)
ser.open()
#Connects to database
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="zzz", # your username
                     passwd="zzz", # your password
                     db="zzz") # name of the data base


cur = db.cursor()
with db:
        cur = db.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM relayschedule WHERE id=1")
        rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        s = str(row)
        ser.write("w" + s)
ser.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide some info. on how your relay information looks like? How are you debugging your arduino code? I would suggest just to print whatever info received on serial console to see whether you are able to receive correct information.

Comment: Hi Praks411, thanks for the reply. The information sent by the python code looks something like this: (1,2,3,4). I debug like this: if I change the python script to just send ser.write(s) and comment out "void serialcommunication()" so the arduino only runs "void Relays()" I receive the information from the python script into the arrays perfectly. This is why I think I need to fix my case statement somehow but am totally lost.

Comment: OH I forgot to add the w. So python sends w(1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think there could be some problem in your Relay function. Also you are inserting too many '\0'
in your inData array which will fail strtok as '\0' is used for terminating string in c. So if strtok see '\0' in the middle of input string (inData) it will terminate the processing.
I think you can try this way. It pretty same to what you are doing with some changes related to inData.

```
void Relays()
{
  while (Serial.available() ==0);
  // Read all serial data available, as fast as possible
  while(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char inChar = Serial.read();
    if(inChar == SOP)
    {
       index = 0;
       started = true;
       ended = false;
    }
    else if(inChar == EOP)
    {
       ended = true;
       inData[index] = '\0';
       break;
    }
    else
    {
      if(index < 79)
      {
        inData[index] = inChar;
        index++;
      }
    }
  }

  // We are here either because all pending serial
  // data has been read OR because an end of
  // packet marker arrived. Which is it?

  if(started && ended)
  {
    // The end of packet marker arrived. Process the packet

    if (strlen(inData) > 0)
   {

      char *token = strtok(inData, ",");
      if(token)
      {
         index = 0;

         array[index] = atoi(token);

         while (token = strtok(NULL, ","))
         {
            array[index++] = atoi(token);
         }
      }
    }

    // Reset for the next packet
    started = false;
    ended = false;
    index = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but unfortunately that didn't work :(